# How to declare defines with exponential

Tags: c++, ios, c-preprocessor, pow, exponential

I'm trying to create the following defines, my source code is shared between an iOS app and a C++ ARM firmware.

```
#define ASSIGN_MIN_VAL_NB_BITS      7
#define ASSIGN_MIN_VAL_BIT_POS      1
#define ASSIGN_MIN_VAL_BIT_MASK     (((2^ASSIGN_MIN_VAL_NB_BITS)-1)<<ASSIGN_MIN_VAL_BIT_POS)
```

I'm expecting ASSIGN_MIN_VAL_BIT_MASK to be 0b11111110, but it is not.
The above 2^ seems to be the problem. How could I declare something similar ?
I've tried using pow(x,y) to replace the 2^, it works but I would like to find a way to declare these define without using runtime functions (I assume pow is a runtime function).

Any idea, tip greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Don't use `#define` for constants in C++, use `const` variables.
2. `^` is bitwise XOR, not exponentiation. `2 to the power of x` can be represented as `1 << x`.

So in your case, the correct expression would be:

```
((1 << ASSIGN_MIN_VAL_NB_BITS) - 1) << ASSIGN_MIN_VAL_BIT_POS
```